# How to set attribute on an object given a dotted path?

Tags: python

Given an object that can be a nested structure of dict-like or array-like objects. What is the pythonic way to set a value on that object given a dotted path as a string?

Example:

```
obj = [
    {'a': [1, 2]},
    {'b': {
        'c': [3, 4],
    }},
]

path = '1.b.c.0'

# operation that sets a value at the given path, e.g.
obj[path] = 5

# or
set_value(obj, path, 5)
```

The above call/assignment should replace the `3` in the example with a `5`.

Note: The path can contain list indices as well as keys. Every level of the object can be an `array` or a `dict` or something that behaves like that.

The solution should be roughly like what the npm package [`object-path`](https://github.com/mariocasciaro/object-path) does in javascript.

Comment: If you have the ability to alter the specification, you might want to consider making the path look something like `[1].b.c[0]` or something like that instead, as that would clearly distinguish which parts are being looked up by index versus being looked up by a string key.

Comment: @DanielPryden Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately I can't alter it. It is defined in [this spec](https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-multipart-request-spec#server). I want to enable a python django backend to process apollo graphql mutations containing file uploads. To be compatible with the reference client implementation I have to keep with that spec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A non-recursive version, which also works for numeric dictionary keys:

```
from collections.abc import MutableMapping

def set_value_at_path(obj, path, value):
    *parts, last = path.split('.')

    for part in parts:
        if isinstance(obj, MutableMapping):
            obj = obj[part]
        else:
            obj = obj[int(part)]

    if isinstance(obj, MutableMapping):
        obj[last] = value
    else:
        obj[int(last)] = value
```

Comment: I like this approach better, for two reasons: first, because it avoids unnecessary recursion, and secondly, because it relies on the data structure to determine how to interpret the tokens in the path rather than the other way around.

Comment: Very good solution thank you. One question: Is an instance of `Mapping` guaranteed to implement `__setitem__`?

Comment: I had a similar (but recursive) solution first. It enables the use of `"1"` as a dictionary key, while it makes usage of `1` as a dictionary key impossible.

Comment: To cover `__setitem__` I guess it shoud be `MutableMapping`, according to the table [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.abc.html).

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a job for recursion and `str.partition`:

```
def set_value(obj, path, val):
    first, sep, rest = path.partition(".")
    if first.isnumeric():
        first = int(first)
    if rest:
        new_obj = obj[first]
        set_value(new_obj, rest, val)
    else:
        obj[first] = val
```

Because `1` is not the same as `"1"`, I'm making a compromise here: If something looks like a number, it's treated as a number.

You could get this to behave on custom objects, but not really on builtin types without awful hackery, because Python doesn't have an equivalent to `object.prototype`.

Comment: I would have done it with a loop rather than recursion (e.g. `for token in path.split('.')`) but this works too.

Comment: Very clean solution. +1 for that. What do you think about trying to cast to an `int` and catch the `ValueError` instead of using `isnumeric()`?

Comment: @trixn I'd say that's a question of personal taste, although you might prefer catching the `ValueError` because "It's easier to ask forgiveness than it is to get permission". If the case where the exception is thrown is frequent, I believe it is slightly slower.